# How do I create a special case Intersect clause in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, intersect

I need a set of values, only when they are available in two different select statements, so I used "intersect"

```
(select statement 1) intersect (select statement 2)
```

but I want all the values from one of the select statements when the other select statement returns with no value.

Example 1:

```
Statement 1 returns(1,2,3,4,5) and Statement 2 returns(2,5,8,9);
Expected result 1: (2,5)
```

Example 2:

```
Statement 1 returns(NULL) and Statement 2 returns(2,5,8,9);
Expected result 1: (2,5,8,9)
```

---Edit: Adding 3rd example for clarity---

Example 3:

```
Statement 1 returns(2,5,8,9) and Statement 2 returns(NULL);
Expected result 1: (2,5,8,9)
```

---Edit 2---
I am using this select in a

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @Magnus I'm using sql-server.

Answer (score 0):

for firts case you could use INNER JOIN

```
select  col 
from  (
  select 1 col union all 
  select 2 union all 
  select 3 union all 
  select 4 union all 
  select 5
) t1  
inner join  (
  select 2 col union all 
  select 5 union all 
  select 8  union all 
  select 9
) t2  ON t1.col = t2.col
```

for the second  you could try  using right join  checking for null value

```
select  col 
from  (
  select 1 col union all 
  select 2 union all 
  select 3 union all 
  select 4 union all 
  select 5
) t1  
right join  (
  select 2 col union all 
  select 5 union all 
  select 8  union all 
  select 9
) t2  ON t1.col = t2.col
where t1.col is null
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using an outer join, if the user wants values on no match?

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL` like this:

```
(
  select statement 1
  union all
  select statement 2  
  where not exists (
    select statement 1
  )
)
intersect
(
  select statement 2
  union all
  select statement 1  
  where not exists (
    select statement 2
  )
)
```

If `select statement X` already contains a `WHERE` clause use `AND` at the end to apply the condition `not exists (...)`.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cef1cc2bde6a06c0ed33ebb5283ce63e).
For these tables:

```
create table table1(id int);
insert into table1(id) values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);

create table table2(id int);
insert into table2(id) values (2), (5), (8), (9);
```

For the case:

```
(
  select * from table1
  union all
  select * from table2  
  where not exists (
    select * from table1
  )
)
intersect
(
  select * from table2
  union all
  select * from table1  
  where not exists (
    select * from table2
  )
)
```

the result is:

```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  2 |
> |  5 |
```

for the case:

```
(
  select * from table1 where id > 9
  union all
  select * from table2  
  where not exists (
    select * from table1 where id > 9
  )
)
intersect
(
  select * from table2
  union all
  select * from table1 where id > 9 
  and not exists (
    select * from table2
  )
)
```

the result is:

```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  2 |
> |  5 |
> |  8 |
> |  9 |
```

and for the case:

```
(
  select * from table1
  union all
  select * from table2 where id > 9 
  and not exists (
    select * from table1
  )
)
intersect
(
  select * from table2 where id > 9
  union all
  select * from table1
  where not exists (
    select * from table2 where id > 9
  )
)
```

the result is:

```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> |  2 |
> |  3 |
> |  4 |
> |  5 |
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do what you want, but you need to place the tables correctly based on where you expect the empty statements to be:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE
(
ID INTEGER
);

DECLARE @t2 TABLE
(
ID INTEGER
);

DECLARE @t3 TABLE
(
ID INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);

INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES (2),(5),(8),(9);

SELECT *
FROM @t1 t1
INNER JOIN @t2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID;

--Example 2, you can use either a FULL JOIN
SELECT *
FROM @t1 t1
FULL JOIN @t3 t3 ON t1.ID = t3.ID;

--Example 2, or you can use a LEFT JOIN. But you need to put the table that is likely to have data as the 
--main table in a LEFT JOIN
SELECT *
FROM @t1 t1
LEFT JOIN @t3 t3 ON t1.ID = t3.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code

```
bool flag := exists (select 1 from Statement_2);
select *
from Statement_1 t1
where exists (select 1 from Statement_2 t2 where t1.key = t2.key) or not flag;
```

Sql server version, replace `key` comparison with a real key.

```
declare @flag bit = case when exists (select 1 from Statement_2)
                   then 1 else 0 end;
select *
from Statement_1 t1
where exists (select 1 from Statement_2 t2 where t1.key = t2.key) or @flag = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be another way:

```
--Setup
create table #table1(id int);
insert into #table1(id) values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);

create table #table2(id int);
insert into #table2(id) values (2), (5), (8), (9);

--Query
select 
    ISNULL(a.id, b.id) id
from
    #table1 a full outer join #table2 b on a.id = b.id
where 
    not exists(select null from #table1) or 
    not exists(select null from #table2) or
    (a.id is not null and b.id is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this to see if it's faster:

```
with
    s1 as (select count(*) over () c1, <query1> ...),
    s2 as (select count(*) over () c2, <query2> ...),
)
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id
from table1 t1 full outer join table2 t2
    on t2.id = t1.id and c1 > 0 and c2 > 0
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do:

```
select t1.id
from t1
where exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.id = t1.id)
union all
select t1.id
from t1
where not exists (select 1 from t2)
union all
select t2.id
from t2
where not exists (select 1 from t1);
```

If your statements are *tables*, then the optimizer should be able to produce efficient execution plans.  If the statements are complicated expressions, then you might need a different approach.  If so, it would be helpful to know what the statement is like.  There may be an optimal way to express the logic with more information.